# How to start or stop AWS Sagemaker hosted instance using Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have a hosted instance (ml.g5.2x large) and am using this to create an AWS Sagemaker inference API point to use in my application via AWS Lambda and API gateway.

I want to set up a process where I can activate or disable the hosted instance based on activity. Basically, if there are no requests made to the model, then I should be able to stop the instance temporarily and restart it again once a request is made via API.

How to do this? Ive already set up the API inference point using AWS Sagemaker, and created a Lambda function and connected with the AWS API gateway.

What are the steps to perform this? Is there a script for performing this action in Lambda?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe sqs, lambda, cloudwatch alarm and so on...